# Linux system-installer for LFS

Tags: linux, installer

I have a Linux from scratch system functioning + some software developed by myself.
I want to launch it as a distro and I need to know how to do that.

I need something like **Debian-installer** or **Anaconda-installer** but I do not know how to go from LFS to a Debian-installer system.

Is it possible to link LFS system to Debian-installer? What do I need to do if I want my system to be installable from live CD?

Thank you.